# Using Swift, how to create a UIViewController over another one using StoryBoards

Tags: uiviewcontroller, storyboard, swift

I have a viewcontroller that hold a button for now, and I want to create a new viewcontroller and add his view over the current one

So far I did this:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    var myController: MyController = MyController.controller()

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!)
    {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(self.myController.view)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender : AnyObject)
    {

    }
}
```

in MyController I did a singleton (I hope I did it right)

```
class MyController : UIViewController
{

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!)
    {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    class func controller() -> MyController
    {
        var once : dispatch_once_t = 0
        var sharedInstance: MyController?

        dispatch_once(&once, { sharedInstance = MyController()})

        return sharedInstance!
    }
}
```

the behavior I got is this, if I DON'T call the

self.view.addSubview(self.myController.view)

everything works fine, if I did, the button in the center is not anymore recognizing the touches, it is like it has something over that intercept the touch, what is wrong here? what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in MyController I did a singleton (I hope I did it right)

You did it wrong. Singleton is not required here. If you are using storyboard, the below line

```
var myController: MyController = MyController.controller()
```

could be

```
var myController: MyController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController")
```

Then before adding sub view set the frame of the `self.myController.view`

```
self.myController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200); // or what ever frame you want
```

Comment: This is not working, I don't know which kind of syntax is this, by the way I can't find a way to set the frame of the uiview

Comment: @Loudequal Sorry. There was a copying error. been edited check now

Comment: ok thanks that's actually working, I ended up doing the same thing, only, I would like to be able to load the UIViewController directly from the StoryBoard instead of creating one and assign to it a frame, how can I just create exactly that UIViewController I have in my StoryBoard?